# Using overwrite in vim but I'd like different behaviour from carriage returns

Tags: command-line, unix, vim

So I'm putting text in a particular area in vim... [image]

I'm using REPLACE mode so that I don't mess up the 'far edge' of the 'rectangle' when I type. It would be great if when I pressed enter in this mode my cursor ended up on the next line without affecting the rest of the line.

But unfortunately when I press enter a new line is inserted and I end up with

[image]

which messes up the 'rectangle' - does anyone have any ideas about how to get the behaviour I'm looking for?

Comment: Your carriage returns _are_ invisible, but they're still _[carriage returns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return)_, which are designed to move the cursor to the start of the next line. What you're looking for is the "down arrow" key.

Comment: Quite right - I've edited the title to make that more clear.  Thank you for your tip about the down arrow - but on my example, the down arrow just moves the cursor down, it doesn't move it 'down and to the start of the next line', which is really what I'm looking for - I hope this clarifies things...

Comment: I suspected that might be what you wanted, but it seems like an unlikely feature. However, there are lots of extensions and hacks for Vim, so maybe someone else has found a way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After tinkering, I came up with the following.  It is a bit of a kluge, but it seems to work:

```
augroup ReplaceReturn
    autocmd!
    autocmd InsertEnter * if v:insertmode ==? 'r' | call s:RedefineReturn() | endif
augroup END

function! s:RedefineReturn()
    inoremap <cr> <down><c-o>0
    inoremap <silent> <esc> <esc>:call <SID>UndefineReturn()<CR>
endfunction

function! s:UndefineReturn()
    if maparg('<cr>', 'i') != ''
        iunmap <cr>
        iunmap <esc>
    endif
endfunction
```